# Debug C# interface implemenation located in nuget package

Tags: c#, debugging, nuget, visual-studio-debugging

I have 3 projects:

- Project A is the main project (.NET Core web application)
- Project B is a class library in a NuGet package holding interfaces
- Project C is a class library in a NuGet package implementing the interface

I managed to build the NuGet packages with pbd symbols and source included. NuGet packages are built in Release mode (may this is the problem?)

I've configured my debugging setup as follows

- *Just My Code* is unticked
- I'm loading the symbols for the two NuGet packages

I can step into all "regular" methods like included extension methods.

But when I reach the interface I can't get it to step into the class implementing the interface. But I can step into code from regular methods from this NuGet package.

Any hints if this is just not possible or I missed ticking something else in the debug settings.

Comment: This can be tricky, if worst comes to worse, just manually reference them, by the time you actually get this working you could have solved the bug 20 times over. anyway good luck

Comment: Yes, that with the 20 times is true (trying to get this now for days). But if I reference them my .csproj files get modified which the build system does not like. Is there a way to have 2 .csproj files side by side and in sync to each other (one for the build server and one for development)?

Comment: You specifically mention that you`re building the NuGet packages in Release mode, but have you tried building them in dev mode? I would at least test it to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a couple of options for you:

- Try to build debug versions of the NuGet packages, and see if it helpt
- Alternatively, remove references to the NuGet packages, and include and reference the projects for them directly, at least temporarily; that should let you debug directly into them.

If nothing else works, there is a third option: Logging.

This may not be exactly the answer you want to hear but in my experience, the best solution to problems such as this may be to add some logging that can be configured to be enabled or disabled as required.

A lot of bugs tend to be caused by missing values, missing references, or some other misconfiguration. Once you find them, they may be trivial to fix, but with implementations "hidden" behind interfaces like this, finding them can be difficult.

Find some way to expose the input-values to your logic, whether it is by logging to a database or just writing a plain-text log to a file, and I'll wager you'll save yourself some time when the next bug comes along, if not before.

...Just remember to disable the logging when you go into production mode, especially if there is any chance the logged data may include any sensitive information.

Comment: As you suggested I tried to build them in Debug mode for testing (still including source and everything, just changed the configuration from release to debug. And oh, hey, I can step into the implementation of the interface.

Comment: Oh dear lord, that part of .NET Core and nugets s__k as h__l. It's pure irony that the ASP.NET Core recommendation is to put everything behind interfaces (for unit testing). Then "introduce a system like nugets" which you can't debug because you can't step into the interface implementations. It seems you can't use a nuget server to deploy Release & Debug side by side since the protocoll does not include the configuration mode & VS2017 does not let you define to load Release from Server X and Debug from Server Y. Use nugets they said. It's the .NET Core way they said. Let's have fun they said.

Comment: Afters spending more than a week to figure out how I could develop again after migrating SharedProjects to nugets I think I could write a book or at least a really long blog post about "How to setup .NET Core development environment when using nugets". With the result that it seems not to work as smooth as it should be.

Comment: @monty It's a pity your having trouble with .NET Core. Glad to hear your immediate problem was solved though. If you *do* write a blog post or anything else about this experience, you might consider linking to it either in your OP, or as a comment below it. It might help someone else later. 
Ps: if this solved your problem, please consider checking is as the "accepted answer" to your question. ;)

Comment: It's more having trouble with coding environment structuring in relation to nugets rather than .NET Core in general. :-) Well, I started with 6 organicaly grown shared projects referecing each other and today ended  up with 25+ nuget package projects, each having 2 .csproj files (one for the build server referencing the nugets, one for development referencing the projects directly). Let's see how this works :-) At least coding and debuggins seems to feel great again. Of course I will accept your answer and thx for the help.